# Why pdf not generate Android Q?

Tags: java, android

Why this not generate the pdf from android version10(Q)
but android version 8 also generate the pdf
please help me ....

`enter code here`
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/SAMPLE.pdf");

```
            try{
            mypdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));

            }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mypdfDocument.close();
            }
```

Comment: Because you can not write directly to the root of external storage with Q.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your manifest, otherwise Android 10 will not allow access. In general, avoid directly accessing storage since it has become much more tricky from Android 11 onwards.

Also,

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`

will no longer return your desired path but will actually return the same path as

`getFilesDir()`.